# Accessing global sass variables and bootstrap in .vue files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, browserify, vue.js

I need my Vue components to inherit styling and variables from other "global" imports.

I do not want to import variables and bootstrap in every single component, this seems very redundant and not best practice.

It is basic usage so Vue must have made the functionality. I have already attempted to create a base component, an "app.vue" component if you will, that has its own styling that includes the variables and bootstrap, but my components can still not access it.

Any idea?

Comment: Another solution to consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411033/1794871. For Vue, I manage all of my .scss files in one place e.g. `App.vue`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no other way than `@import` the variables file in each component. Much like we have to import/require the npm libs we use in each component.

Comment: For anyone using Bootstrap 4 you will need to import `_functions.scss` first before importing `_variables.scss`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with webpack's sass loader options that name is 'prependData'. This code will be added top of every .vue file that consist of scss style. I know this is ugly but It works.  As bootstrap documentation said. You have two choices about this. One of these is adding whole bootstrap files another one is this technique.

You can check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/) bootstrap documentation.

```
// webpack.config.js

      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        prependData: "@import '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss'; @import '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss'; @import '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss';"
      }
```