# Accessing bootstrap scss variables in angular 2 component

Tags: angular, sass

I'm working on a new Angular2 project built using Angular CLI and have configured the project to use SCSS. I have Bootstrap 4 successfully loaded into my `styles.scss` file however if I try and access any of Bootstrap's (or my own variables defined in `styles.scss` from within a component I get `Undefined Variable` build error.

Are the style files for components compiled before the main entry in the `styles` node of `angular-cli.json`? How can I make is so that any variables defined at that global level are available to all components in the application? Thanks!

**angular-cli.json**

```
"apps": [
  {
    ...
    "styles": [
      "styles/styles.scss"
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

**styles.scss**

```
// Bootstrap
$enable-flex: true; // Enable Flexbox mode
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**component**

```
.navbar {
  background: $brand-primary; // Undefined variable here
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just because you are importing the bootstrap 4 into your `styles.scss` doesn't mean your `.scss` files on your components have access to that.

On your `component.scss` you have to import the Bootstrap variables:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';

.navbar {
  background: $brand-primary; // No more Undefined variable here
}
```

### Explanation

A lot of people seem to me confused by this, you should not import `bootstrap.scss` to your components you should only import the things that you need.

If you look closely into [the source code of bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss) they have everything separated in different files. You have the `mixins` folder and the `_variables.scss` file. Those should be the only things you import on your component to avoid CSS duplication.

> Would this increase my bundle size, importing these things on every component?

No, it won't. Why? `mixins` and `variables` are sass specific (at least for now) so when you import all the variables into your component like this:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';

.navbar {
  background: $brand-primary;
}
```

the output CSS of that will be:

```
.navbar {
  background: #007bff;
}
```

The rest of the variables will be discarded after compiling to CSS.

Comment: If I have a dozen components, won't the `_variables.scss` file be read a dozen times?

Comment: Yes it will be read, but not included in the code, remember that css doesn't have variables

Comment: What's with the `~` tilde character? Is that how you reference `[/*/**]/node_modules/{{packageName}}` in SCSS? Similar to `@angular/core/...` in TS?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, except the TS part, you don't need a @ to reference a package from the node modules. In TS and node any absolute imports will resolve to node_modules

Comment: @FabioAntunes css have variables :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a _colors.scss file, copy all the color variables inside and import that file in your component.scss file.

Answer (score 4):

A few people have suggested `@import`-ing the `variables.scss` in every component `.scss` but I found this a little messy. Doing so did not also work well with the way our company CSS is architectured. I ended up going in this direction to enable me to use the variables, mixins, and also extend styles. This also allows me to manage all of the CSS in one location.

I'm currently working on a project that has been generated by Angular2 CLI. So there is a main style.scss

---

Another way I was able to accomplish this is by doing the following:

1. Removing the `styleUrls` from the `app.component.ts` files.

   ```
   @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       templateUrl: './app.component.html'
       // styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   });
   ```
2. I manage all the less files in the main `styles.scss`. So my current setup looks something like:

   ```
   // Bootstrap
   @import "../node_modules/bootstrap-less/bootstrap/index";

   // Company Branding
   @import "theme/index";

   // Components
   @import "app/app.component.scss";
   @import "app/search/search.component.scss";
   ```

---

Hopefully this alternative solution will be helpful to someone.

Comment: This should work, but this way you are probably not able to leverage view-encapsulation. I suppose you have to change your components to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @hgoebl yeah that will not work. I use encapsulation differently. In our coding style we always have a selector that differentiates the pages. Instead of using `encapsulation` we just use the specific selector for that page.

Comment: A quick test revealed: Duplicate imports apparently do not impact filesize. Just checked this with a couple of components and the effective file size remained the same whether I would include _variable.scss in every single component or not (I did not check the docs or even the implementation though). So @fabio-antunes 's answer is probably better for it doesn't break encapsulation.

Comment: But if you import whole bootstrap.scss into each component scss file, then the main.bundle.js blow out of proportion for each component create a bunch of component related definitions.

Comment: @IgorBabic why would you import the whole bootrap.scss to your components when you only want the the variables or mixins? You should only import what you need.