# 'SassError undefined variable' with Angular 9 and Bootstrap 4 out-of-the-box

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Previously I have used Angular 8 with Bootstrap 4, and used this excellent answer in order to access Bootstrap variables.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070580/1061602.

I cannot seem to get this working with Angular 9.

Steps:

1. Generate a new project with Angular CLI, choosing SCSS
2. Install Bootstrap 4, JQuery, Popper.js via npm
3. In styles.scss, enter the following:
   `html { background: $success-bg; }`
4. Run `ng b` to build

You now get `SassError: Undefined variable`

[image]

**Q: What import is needed in order to import Bootstrap 4 at SCSS level, AND also be able to use the variables**

I have tried combinations of the following:

`@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

`@import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables";`

`@import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";`

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";`

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";`

e.g. 
[image]

I tried setting up a StackBlitz but couldn't find a way of getting Angular 9, SCSS, Bootstrap 4 all set up, it was complaining about CSS instead of SCSS.

Generally speaking, Bootstrap works. The utility classes work. I can use mixins. I can re-define variables with no problem. I just can't *use* existing BS4 variables in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import variables before you use, I use the following setup

```
// Required Bootstrap partials
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

html { background: $success-bg; }

// Optional (Add components according to your use)
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me, I've attached a screenshot showing all the imports I've added

Answer (score 1):

You may have put a non-existent variable.

Go to your bootstrap's variables file (inside node_modules if you install with npm, or any folder if you download manually), it usually have a name of _variables.scss.

Then find your wanted variable to be reused in your code.

Comment: that could be a reason for the error, but in this example following the steps the variable `$success-bg;` exists - or at least it did at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

It 'might' not be an import issue. I think the 'background' variable isn't actually defined in your './variables/scss' file. You could try opening the file then declaring the variable like this; $background: property_value;

I was working on a bootstrap template I got online, and it gave me a similar error, but with a variable $white that sets the color to white, so I had to define the variable and assign it color white. I hope it helps.

Comment: this may have been downvoted as it is a similar response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/71346069/1061602. so yes that is the 'genuine reason' for the error message, in this case the variable was defined it was a problem importing the variables file.